# ExpandableListView OnChildClickListener with checkbox row not fire when scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have an BaseExpandableListAdapter look like this:

```
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ContentViewHolder contentViewHolder;
    View view = convertView;
    final Book book = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition); 
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_book_row, null);
        contentViewHolder = new ContentViewHolder();
        contentViewHolder.tvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        contentViewHolder.chkSelected = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkSelected);
        view.setTag(contentViewHolder);
    }else{
        contentViewHolder = (ContentViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }        

    contentViewHolder.tvName.setText(book.getTitle());
    contentViewHolder.chkSelected.setChecked(checkStates[groupPosition][childPosition]);

    contentViewHolder.chkSelected.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            book.setSelected(contentViewHolder.chkSelected.isChecked());
            checkStates[groupPosition][childPosition] = contentViewHolder.chkSelected.isChecked();
            Ln.d("check on header %d row %d", groupPosition, childPosition);

        }
    });

    return view;
}

  public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
     Ln.d("Child selected "+groupPosition+" : "+childPosition);    
    return true;
}
```

with the child layout:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
<!-- Row data -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TextView>
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkSelected"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/item_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/item_vertical_margin" />  
  </RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the fragment view:

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >    
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/lstCatBook"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:groupIndicator="@null">
  </ExpandableListView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Then I register `setOnChildClickListener` on my fragment.

```
  lstCatBook.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            Log.d("Click on group " +groupPosition +" child " + childPosition);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Everything is fine when I click on row item or checkbox. But the problem is when I scroll listview to the bottom, I can't click on row item again (the `onChildClick` not fired ) while check box can work 
 
I have no ideas with this issue.
I have searched and tried many ways like: set check box `focusable = false`, `descendantFocusability=blocksDescendants` but nothing can help. 
Where am I wrong? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I figure out the problem: cause I use set Expand for all group if listview. I don't know why `setOnChildClickListener` doesn't work in this case. But I can work around by catch the click event on convert view from getChildView and then notify for the main view.

Something like that:

```
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
    boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  //load data
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // notify for main view by using another listener
    }
   });
   return converview;
 }
```